# VSCode Debugger on Jupyter Notebook doesn't stop running

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, breakpoints, vscode-debugger

I want to debug a Jupiter notebook in VSCode, that access multiple other .py scripts with class methods. I've set a breaking point in the respective cell, but the debugger keeps running infinitely and I got no results neither in variables section nor in call stack section and my debug console just remains empty.

I would be grateful if there is any idea why the debugger is stuck.

This is what I have in my launch.json:

```
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },
        {
            "name": "Debug Unit Test",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch", //launch or attach
            "justMyCode": false,
        }
    ]
}
```

VSCode Info:

```
Version: 1.64.2 (Universal)
Commit: f80445acd5a3dadef24aa209168452a3d97cc326
Date: 2022-02-09T22:00:58.347Z
Electron: 13.5.2
Chromium: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 20.6.0
```